# Applying lambda function to datetime

Tags: python, lambda

I am using the following code to find clusters with difference <=1 in a list

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
data = [ 1, 4,5,6, 10, 15,16,17,18, 22, 25,26,27,28]
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(data), lambda (i, x): (i-x)):
    print map(itemgetter(1), g)
```

If however I change the `data` to be an array of datetime to find cluster of datetimes which are only 1 hour apart, it fails.

I am trying the following:

```
>>> data
array([datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 1, 8, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 1, 9, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 1, 10, 0), ...,
       datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 3, 9, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 3, 10, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 3, 11, 0)], dtype=object)

    from itertools import groupby
    from operator import itemgetter
    data = [ 1, 4,5,6, 10, 15,16,17,18, 22, 25,26,27,28]
    for k, g in groupby(enumerate(data), lambda (i, x): (i-x).total_seconds()/3600):
        print map(itemgetter(1), g)
```

The error is:

```
    for k, g in groupby(enumerate(data), lambda (i, x): int((i-x).total_seconds()/3600)):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

There are lot of solutions on the web but I want to apply this particular one for learning.

Comment: At the moment you are comparing an item (`datetime`) with it's index (`int`) in the list. Shouldn't you be comparing each two subsequent items?

Comment: how do you mean? what is the change I need to try?

Comment: If you want to find all subsequences with each item being an hour later than the previous one, you should be iterating over pairs of `datetime` objects: `(data[0], data[1]), (data[1], data[2]), ..., (data[n-2], data[n-1])`. See [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain). At the moment you are just iterating over a list of pairs `(0, data[0]), (1, data[1]), ..., (n-1, data[n-1])` which raises `TypeError` because you can't substract a `datetime` object from an `int`.

Comment: Can you please suggest the modification in my code as I understand what you are saying but don't know how to syntax it?

Comment: Sure, will do. And sorry, I've meant `itertools.izip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all subsequences of items such that each item is an hour later than the previous one (not clusters of items that each are within an hour from eachother), you need to iterate over pairs `(data[i-1], data[i])`. Currently, you are just iterating over `(i, data[i])` which raises `TypeError` when you try to substract `data[i]` from `i`. A working example could look like this:

```
from itertools import izip

def find_subsequences(data):
    if len(data) <= 1:
        return []

    current_group = [data[0]]
    delta = 3600
    results = []

    for current, next in izip(data, data[1:]):
        if abs((next - current).total_seconds()) > delta:
            # Here, `current` is the last item of the previous subsequence
            # and `next` is the first item of the next subsequence.
            if len(current_group) >= 2:
                results.append(current_group)

            current_group = [next]
            continue

        current_group.append(next)

    return results
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but for educational reasons I was looking to implement my version of code using lambda functions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's import datetime, and take out the elipsis from your data, and then apply a lambda function with two nested loops to calculate elapsed time between any two dates lower than one hour... a boolean matrix will identify the desired clusters easily.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
        
data = np.array([dt(2016, 10, 1, 8, 0),
    dt(2016, 10, 1, 9, 0),
    dt(2016, 10, 1, 10, 0),
    dt(2019, 1, 3, 9, 0),
    dt(2019, 1, 3, 10, 0),
    dt(2019, 1, 3, 11, 0)], dtype=object)
    
mds = lambda ds: [[abs(da-db).seconds/3600 <= 1 for da in ds] for db in ds]
```

Appling the function to data:

```
md = mds(data)
```

md will give us:

```
[[True, True, False, True, False, False],
 [True, True, True, True, True, False],
 [False, True, True, False, True, True],
 [True, True, False, True, True, False],
 [False, True, True, True, True, True],
 [False, False, True, False, True, True]]
```

Note that the main diagonal is `True` (Deltatime is zero), and the matrix is symmetrical. True elements are those where `abs(date[i] - date[j])` is lower or equal to one hour, i and j between 0 and 5 indicates each pair of dates that are considerated at the matrix.